# c++ Используя перегрузку функции написать программу вычисления произведения двух переменных разного типа

Tags: c++, функции

На языке C++
Используя перегрузку функции написать программу вычисления произведения двух переменных разного типа (int, long, float, double). Как я понимаю, нужно иметь возможность перемножнить переменные именно разных типов. Например int c  float, float c double. Это вообще реально реализовать?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем функции, если и так можно написать умножение `a*b`?... Что, интересно, хотят увидеть преподы? Нуежели просто набор функций из одной строчки?

Comment: Ну это просто тренировка владения функциями, а у Вас есть решение?

Comment: кто-то уже покажет работающий код или нет?))

Answer (score 5):

Решение? вот:

```
string types[] = { "short", "int", "long", "long long", "float", "double" };
for(int i = 0; i < size(types); ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < size(types); ++j)
    {
        cout << setw(9) << left << types[i > j ? i : j] << "  mul(" << setw(9)
            << types[i] << " a, " << setw(9) << types[j] << " b) { return a*b; }\n";
    }
```

Результат работы этой программы:

```
short      mul(short     a, short     b) { return a*b; }
int        mul(short     a, int       b) { return a*b; }
long       mul(short     a, long      b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(short     a, long long b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(short     a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(short     a, double    b) { return a*b; }
int        mul(int       a, short     b) { return a*b; }
int        mul(int       a, int       b) { return a*b; }
long       mul(int       a, long      b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(int       a, long long b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(int       a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(int       a, double    b) { return a*b; }
long       mul(long      a, short     b) { return a*b; }
long       mul(long      a, int       b) { return a*b; }
long       mul(long      a, long      b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(long      a, long long b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(long      a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(long      a, double    b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(long long a, short     b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(long long a, int       b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(long long a, long      b) { return a*b; }
long long  mul(long long a, long long b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(long long a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(long long a, double    b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(float     a, short     b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(float     a, int       b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(float     a, long      b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(float     a, long long b) { return a*b; }
float      mul(float     a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(float     a, double    b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, short     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, int       b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, long      b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, long long b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, float     b) { return a*b; }
double     mul(double    a, double    b) { return a*b; }
```

Устраивает? :)

Comment: просто лайк))))

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
int mul(int a, int b){return a*b;}
float mul(float a, float b){return a*b;}
double mul(double a, double b){return a*b;}
```

UPD1:

Вот для переменных разных типов:

```
float mul(int a, float b){return a*b;}
float mul(float a, int b){return a*b;}

double mul(float a, double b){return a*b;}
double mul(double a, float b){return a*b;}
```

Ну и так далее, там вариантов много будет.

Comment: ну тут же перемножаются только две перемнные одного типа

Answer (score 1):

С шаблонами можно так,

```
template <typename T, typename V>
    auto mul(T& a, V& b) {
        return a * b;
    }
```

Comment: Человеку надо не тему "шаблоны" сдать, а тему "пререгрузка функций". :-)

Comment: А зачем передавать ссылки? Чтоб не дай Бог, не написать `mul(2,3)`?