# Перегрузка функций и шаблоны в С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-функций

Вдогонку к вопросу о перегрузке функций:

[c++ Используя перегрузку функции написать программу вычисления произведения двух переменных разного типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112289/c-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85)

Получается, что шаблоны сделали перегрузку функций ненужной (в С++)? Или есть все-таки варианты, когда шаблоны не могут заменить перегрузку функций?

Comment: Ну почему же? Например, если нужно только несколько вариантов - нет смысла заморачиваться шаблонами. Или если каждая функция должна работать по-своему - какой смысл в шаблоне с массой специализаций? Да и при поиске шаблоны стоят дальше функций...

Comment: @Harry Смысл в том, чтобы не плодить лишние сущности. Если механизм шаблонов более общий, то логично пользоваться только им.

Comment: @Harry [при поиске шаблоны стоят дальше функций] При каком поиске и где это дальше?

Comment: Ну пользуйтесь только им :) Правая рука обычно развитее левой - так чтоб не плодить лишние сущности, левую нужно... да ладно, просто привязать к туловищу :)

Comment: Если есть функция и шаблон с одним именем - то функция считается более подходящей, чем шаблон. Этим можно пользоваться вместо специализации...

Comment: По-хорошему да, но так как в С++ шаблоны появились уже после перегрузки функций и были прикручены через одно место с сохранением работоспособности ранее написанного кода с перегрузками, то нет. Собственно даже сами шиблоны функций требуют написания перегрузок из-за разных ограничений (например в шаблонах позиционный параметр должен быть либо типом, либо нет, также не разрешена частичная специализация)

Comment: @Harry Насчет руки хороший пример. У змей вообще руки-ноги атрофировались чтобы лишний корм не тратить и ничего - змеи процветают.

Comment: @user7860670 Сейчас, конечно, перегрузку функций уже не отменишь (из-за проблем с обратной совместимостью), но получается, что более общий механизм сделал неактуальным менее общий механизм.

Comment: Заодно - к более общий - более громоздкий, более сложный, менее интуитивный... Впрочем, если вы уже уверовали - зачем спрашивать? :)

Comment: @Harry [зачем спрашивать?] Чтобы проверить свою гениальную догадку. А что касается того, что шаблоны в С++ более громоздки, чем перегрузка, то это не беда. Язык С++ (как и все в этом мире) это не навсегда. Будут и другие языки, с более простым синтаксисом шаблонов. И вот тогда, из слез, из темноты, из бедного невежества былого, надо будет учесть, что шаблоны это более общий механизм, и при наличии шаблонов от перегрузки функций можно отказаться.

Comment: Шаблоны устанавливают общее правило. Если нужно всего два варианта функции,    а все остальные варианты будут логически неверными или не нужными, зачем я буду писать шаблон и  две его специализации, а потом еще запрещать все остальные варианты?...  Не думаю, что частные дома перестанут быть нужным, при возможности строить "муровейники"...  Простая функция_член контейнера  `begin` требует две перегрузки для константного и не константного объекта. Написать для этого шаблон?...

Comment: @pepsicoca1, похоже вы задумались о С++ "вообще", молодец

Comment: @avp [вы задумались о С++ "вообще"] А что делать? Тут поневоле задумаешься. Мне, как и всем, тоже надоело постоянно писать слово "template". :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1, пора значит подумать о чем-то другом, придумать свой хороший язык

Comment: @avp [придумать свой хороший язык] Я уже написал интерпретатор Basic, а у меня договоренность со Страуструпом - он не пишет интерпретаторы Basic, а я не придумываю новый синтаксис для функционала языка С++.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, неужели в моих комментариях было хоть что-то о новом функционале С++?

Comment: @avp Нет, речь идет о новом синтаксисе для старого функционала С++. Чтобы не писать слово "template" на каждой строчке.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, а вы так и не поняли, что смысл послания --  отказ от крестов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, шаблоны далеко не всегда заменяют перегрузку функций. Шаблоны совсем не помогают, если функции должны делать разное. Как, например, заменить шаблоном такую пару перегруженных функций?

```
double CalcSum(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}

void CalcSum(double x, double y,double& res) {
    res = x + y;
}
```

Даже если сделать так:

```
template<typename... Args> double CalcSum(Args...) { return 0; }

template<> double CalcSum<double,double>(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

template<> double CalcSum<double, double,double&>(double x, double y, double& res)
{
    res = x + y;
    return res;
}
```

То проблема этого кода (помимо того, что он выглядит ужасно), в том что он все равно не вполне работает как нужно. Если просто писать `CalcSum(1.0, 2.0, res)`, нужная специализация вызываться не будет - нужно писать `CalcSum<double, double, double&>(1.0, 2.0, res);`...